# powershell AD how to check if user exist and if not then create it

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
function CreateUSR ([string]$name, [string]$path) {
$test = "OU=$name,$path"

$VerbosePreference = "Continue"

# Check if the user exists
try  {
    get-ADUser -Identity $test  | Out-Null
    Write-Verbose "OU '$test'already exists."
}

catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException] {
    Write-Verbose "Creating new User '$test'"
    New-ADUser -name $name -Path $path
}

catch {
"An error occurred that could not be resolved."} 
}
New-ADUser -name "Flip" -path "OU=testorganization,DC=NET,DC=DSAS,DC=NL" -OtherAttributes @{'title'="director" ;'mail'="test@test"}
```

Comment: Are you sure the user should have it's own OU? (`OU=$name`)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `get-ADUser -Identity $test  | Out-Null` you can use

```
if (!(Get-aduser -filter {samaccountname -eq $test})){
    Write-Verbose "Creating new User $test"
    New-ADUser -name $name -Path $path
} else {
    write-host "User $test already exist!"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but still the same error.

Comment: @Hugo What's the error message?

Comment: @Hugo: please try the code now, the if condition needed to be inversed. sorry for that i wrote the answer from mobile :D

Comment: @Hugo Is that error from the last line where you have a hardcoded name of "Flip"?

Comment: @GabrielLuci 
```New-ADUser : The specified account already exists
At C:\Users\Administrator.D002\Desktop\OU.ps1:45 char:1
+ New-ADUser -name "FLIP" -path "OU=000Organization,DC=NET,DC=COMPany ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (CN=FLIP,OU=COMPanyLO...nederland,DC=NL:String) [New-ADUser], ADIdentityAlreadyExistsException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1316,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser```

Comment: @GabrielLuci yes the last rule if the name flip is there then it must do nothing if it is not there then it must be created

Comment: @Hugo The way your code is written, that last line will always run. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @Gabriel Luci
No indeed, it actually have to check is the user in the AD, if yes then say theuseris already in. If not then create the user

Comment: @Hugo Ok, but your last line (`New-ADUser -name "Flip"`) doesn't have any condition around it. It will always run and always use the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, instead of passing a *Path* as parameter, it's easier to use an *OU Name* and search for it. I have added an `if` condition that considers the possibility that more than one OU with the same name can be found, I have not tested it's functionality and this should of course be improved.

```
function CreateUSR {
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$Name,
    [parameter(
        Mandatory,
        HelpMessage = 'Name of the OU where the user should be created.'
    )]
    [string]$OUName
)

    $ou = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter "(name=$OUName)"
    $user = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$Name)"

    if(-not $ou)
    {
        throw "$OUName could not be found on this Domain."
    }
    if($ou.Count -gt 1)
    {
        @(
            "More than one OU with name $OUName was found."
            "Choose one using the Index Number!"
        ) | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red

        $ou.foreach({
            begin { $i = 0 }
            process { "$i - {0}" -f $_.DistinguishedName; $i++ }
        })

        [int]$index = Read-Host 'Index'
        $ou = $ou[$index]
    }
    if($user)
    {
        throw "$user already exists!"
    }

    New-ADUser -Name $Name -Path $ou
}
```